# Finding Horizontal pairs in a C multidimensional array

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, function-pointers

I have been struggling for a while with my program.  I am trying to find horizontal pairs in an array that is setup in function1.  My goal is to change the original array in another function.  Then process that array to find a horizontal pair.

One problem that has occurred is when I run the program, the result is zero.  Another problem is the *gcc warning* in function 1, warning: comparison between pointer and integer.  The other problem is another *gcc warning* (marked by the **) warning: passing argument 1 of 'function1' from incompatible pointer type.

I appreciate any help, as a beginner, I have spent several hours on this problem and have tried to find solutions, but trying to use pointers and using *struct* and *typedef* have not worked. :(

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void function1 (int letter1[][16]);
void function2 (int letter2[][16]);

int  main ( void )
{  

  int letter_array [13][16];

  printf("\n \t\t Hello!");
  printf("\n This program will create a random selection of 180 upper-case"
    " characters. \n");

  **function1(&letter_array);**

  function2(letter_array);

return ( 0 ) ;
}    


void function1 (int letter1 [][16])
{
  int i, z; 
  srandom((unsigned)time(NULL));

  for(i=0; i<=11; i++)
    {
       for(z=0; z<=14; z++)
       {
          letter1 [i][z] = random( )%26+65;
          printf("%c ", letter1 [i][z]);
       }
       printf("\n");
    }

  return ;
  }

void function2 (int letter2 [][16])
  {
  int a,b; 
  int m=0;
    for( a = 0; a <= 11; a++)
    {
       for( b = 0 ; b <= 14; b++)
       {
            if (letter2 == (letter2 + 1))
            m++;
       }
    }
  printf("\nThe number of horizontal pairs of characters"
    " are: %d", m);

  return ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the ampersand `&` from the argument.

Change

```
function1(&letter_array);
```

to

```
function1(letter_array);
```

EDIT:
Also change

```
if (letter2 == (letter2 + 1))
```

to

```
if (letter2[a][b] == (letter2[a][b+1]))
```

Comment: Probably also better to use `letter1[i][z] = random() % 26 + 'A';` instead of the magic number 65.

Comment: what difference would it make?

Comment: Readability to indicate what the code is trying to do. The magic number doesn't make it immediately clear why he's adding the numbers and what they represent. I'd even go so far as to write it as `(char)(random() % 26 + 'A')` with a comment that says "Generate a random letter from A-Z"

Comment: @Tawnos I thought about doing that, but I was not sure of the shell that would be used by others to compile the program.  Harry's book has said some shells do look order from A-Z, others will order from Aa-xZ.  The shell I use, the random letter A-Z would have been fine.

Comment: @ skrtbhtngr  You're right.  I don't know why I couldn't put it together, but I had the sneaking suspicion that my array wasn't being changed in *function1*.  So, my efforts were mostly in "fixing" the relation between *function1* and *main()*.

Comment: What does a shell used to compile have to do with it?

Answer (score 1):

The warning is occurring because you are passing a pointer to an array[][16] into function1 instead of the array itself. This can be resolved by removing the &:

```
function1(letter_array);
```

The program is returning 0 because of the return statement at the end of your main function.